# In ASP.NET MVC Core do CRUD operations follow the Repository Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc, repository

In some MVC frameworks I've used the Model has the method and SQL in the Model so that if you call the controller, it invokes a method on the model class (say Products), and it returns the data.  In ASP.NET MVC Core, from what I have seen so far, there is a separate file besides the model to do the logic.  Do I use two classes?  They appear (the ones I read) to be using the Repository Pattern.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

That's one class.  Where do the methods to get the data go?  Is the Repository Pattern necessary or it is a "Best Practice"?

```
public interface IStoreRepository
{
    //CRUD signatures
}

public ProductRepository : IStoreRepository
{

    //CRUD implementation
}
....

public IActionResult Products()
{
//A controller
//Call method in ProductRepository.GetAll or the like
}
```

If it matters I am attempting to use Dapper, not EF.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC doesn't have much to say about what you're asking. Everything you described is part of the Model; the design of the Model is entirely up to you.

However, you can get [some rudimentary guidance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model) from the ASP.NET site. If you dig in there, you will find code that looks like this:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public MoviesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Movies
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Which is about as straightforward as it gets.  As you can see, the data for the returned View is being drawn directly from an Entity Framework `DBContext` object.

In larger applications, you're probably going to want a more structured approach to your Model. Something like this:

```
DATABASE <=> Entity Framework <=> Service Layer <=> Controller <=> ViewModel <=> View
```

Where the Service Layer exposes business domain-specific methods, rather than CRUD.  But again, none of this really has much to do with ASP.NET MVC proper.